# How can I resume Activity B from Activity C?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have 3 classes A,B,C.

Class A am passing 3 values to class B and class B am passing 3 values to class C.
In class C I have one back button if I click this back button I want to resume my activity B.

I am new for android; I don't know much about activity life cycle. Thanks in advance.

This is my code.

```
public class A extends Activity
{
    EditText one,two,three;Button sub;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.one);
        this.onWindowFocusChanged(true);
        one=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.one);
        two=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.one);
        three=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.one);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b.putString("one",one.getText().toString());
                b.putString("two",two.getText().toString());
                b.putString("three",three.getText().toString());
                b.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the class B Activity

```
public class B extends Activity
{
    EditText one,two,three;Button sub;String one1,two1,three1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.two);
        this.onWindowFocusChanged(true);
        one=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.one);
        two=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.one);
        three=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.one);
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        one1=b.getString("one");
        one.setText(one1);
        two1=b.getString("two");
        two.setText(two1);
        three1=b.getString("three");
        three.setText(three1);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b.putString("one",one.getText().toString());
                b.putString("two",two.getText().toString());
                b.putString("three",three.getText().toString());
                b.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is class C Activity (**where the app crashes**)

```
public class C extends Activity
{
    EditText one,two,three;Button sub,back;String one1,two1,three1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.three);
        this.onWindowFocusChanged(true);
        one=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.one);
        two=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.one);
        three=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.one);
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        one1=b.getString("one");
        one.setText(one1);
        two1=b.getString("two");
        two.setText(two1);
        three1=b.getString("three");
        three.setText(three1);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() 
    {
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //Clicking back button i want to resume the activity b class but its getting crashed
                Intent i = new Intent(C.this, B.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Whenever I click this back button the app crashes, not resuming my Activity B.

Comment: I'll mention this because you said you're a newbie, but you don't need all of those `onResume()`, `onStart()`, etc. methods unless you do something in them.

Comment: ok put one vote for me i will accept your answer..

Comment: can you post error log please while app crash on back button

Comment: its working but when i give finish() in activity B and in Activity C if i click back button it will crashed because am using bundle in activity b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your back button listener with this in your Activity C class:

```
back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

It will close your current Activity (C), and therefore resume your Activity that was active before it (B).

Comment: Android devices already have a Back button. You should use that instead of creating a new one. There is nothing you can do with a new button that you cannot do with the one that the Android system provides.

Comment: @Varatharaj.... yes because otherwise, if you open Activity B back up with an intent, it won't close your Activity C.

Comment: i want to create one back in my activity bacause every time i want to close my current acticity and want to open new activity?

Comment: @Varatharaj.... if you want to close the activity from which you are sending data, and then start the activity on back press, just make sure you send in a bundle to the activity. since when it reaches onCreate, it would look for a bundle and not receive and data therefore crash. Hope that helps.

Comment: yes dude i know but any other way to resume the activity after finish();

Comment: @Varatharaj.... no there is no other way, once an activity has been finished you need to start it again.

Answer (score 2):

To close the C activity and resume the last one, use `finish();`

So for example, put `finish();` in your back button listener

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
public class Main1Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```